# When solving PDE, why this ansatz?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$ u_{tt}(x,t)-c^2 u_{xx}(x,t)=K $$
$$ u_x (0,t)=u_t (x,0) = u(L,t) = u(x,0) = 0 $$

Since I have a non-homogenous differential equation, I can't use variable of separations and as such, I begin by creating a particular (stationary) and a homogenous solution;

$$ u(x,t) = u_{stat}(x) + v(x,t) $$

The problem for $u_{stat}$ is

$$ -c^2 u_{stat}''(x)=K, \quad u'_{stat}(0)=u_{stat}(L)=0$$

The solution for this is pretty easy so I will just write it out as

$$u_{stat}(x)=\frac{K}{2c^2} (L^2-x^2)$$

Now to the problem of $v(x,t)$, which is defined below. The constraints were derived from $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-u_{stat}(x)$.

$$ v_{tt} - c^2 v_{xx} = 0 $$
$$ v_x (0,t) = v_t (x,0) = v(L,t) = 0, \quad v(x,0) = -u_{stat} (x)$$

Since we have homogenous boundary conditions (non-homogenous initial conditions though) and a homogenous differential equation, I tried using variable of separation. Trivial solutions were gained for $\lambda>0, \lambda=0$. When $\lambda=\omega^2 <0$, I got $X(x)=Acos(\omega x)$, and $T(t)=\frac{K}{2c^2} (x^2-L^2) cos(c\omega x)$, where $\omega = \frac{\pi}{L}(\frac{1}{2}+n), n=0,1,2,...$

It seems like I have solved the question wrongly though, because when I got the correct solution to this problem, I saw that an ansatz had been made for $v(x,t)$, which was

$$ v(x,t) = \sum_n a_n(t)f_n(x) $$

Here, $f_n (x)$ has the same solution as my $X(x)$, but $a_n(t)$ was solved by putting $f_n (x)$ back into the PDE for $v(x,t)$, and then solving the ODE-problem defined as

$$ a_n ''(t) + (ck_n)^2 a_n(t) = 0, \quad a_n (0) = -\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f_n(x)u_{stat}(x)dx, \quad a_n' (0) = 0 $$

*My question;*

How did they derive the ODE initial conditions (not the ODE itself)?
Is there any way to predict or intuitively understand why we should make the sum-ansatz for $v(x,t)$ instead of trying to use separation of variables, which I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you did it. The ansatz made by whoever wrote the solution **is** an application of separation of variables, very similar to your approach. First, though, there is an issue with your solution, which I'll address below.

To start, your eigenfunction for $T(t)$ is wrong, and certainly should not contain any terms in $x$. When solving the ODEs in $X$ and $T$, you only the apply *homogeneous* conditions. Once you have done that, construct your solution as a Fourier series, *then* apply the *inhomogeneous* condition.

Following above, the solution to $T'' = - c^{2} \omega^{2} T$ (where $\omega$ is the eigenvalue you found) with the homogeneous boundary condition

$$v_{t}(x,0) = 0 \implies T'(0) = 0 \tag 1$$ is given by

$$T_{n}(t) = B_{n} \cos \left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi c t}{2L} \right)$$

This yields the solution for $v$ as a Fourier series

\begin{align}
v(x,t) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} X_{n}(x) T_{n}(t) \\
&\sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} \cos \left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L} \right) \cos \left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi c t}{2L} \right) \tag 2
\end{align}

Substituting in the *inhomogeneous* boundary condition, we find

\begin{align} 
v(x,0) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} \cos \left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L} \right) \\ 
&= -u_{\text{stat}}(x) \tag 3
\end{align}

and multiplying both sides by $\cos \left( \frac{(2m+1)\pi x}{2L} \right)$ and integrating over the domain $x \in [0,L]$ gives

\begin{align} 
\sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} \int_{0}^{L} \cos \left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L} \right) \cos \left( \frac{(2m+1)\pi x}{2L} \right) dx &= - \int_{0}^{L} u_{\text{stat}}(x) \cos \left( \frac{(2m+1)\pi x}{2L} \right) dx
\end{align}

which yields the coefficients (for $n = m$)

\begin{align}
A_{n} = - \frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L} u_{\text{stat}}(x) \cos \left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L} \right) dx \tag 4
\end{align}

and hence after solving the above integrals, you have the solution to your PDE as a Fourier series.

Now, imagine after doing separation of variables that you *hadn't* yet solved the ODE in $T$ but had only solved the ODE in $X$, given by $X'' = - \omega^{2} X$. Then, as we know the solution will be a Fourier series, we can assume the solution $v(x,t)$ takes the general form

$$v(x,t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} X_{n}(x) T_{n}(t)$$

which is essentially what we have written at $(2)$ (note that our $X_{n}(x) = \cos \left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L} \right)$ is the solutions $f_{n}(x)$. Similarly, $T_{n}(t) = a_{n}(t)$). Substituting into the PDE yields

\begin{align}
v_{tt} - c^{2} v_{xx} &= \sum_{n \ge 0} X_{n}(x) T''_{n}(t) - c^{2} \sum_{n \ge 0} X''_{n}(x) T_{n}(t) \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} X_{n}(x) T''_{n}(t) - c^{2} X''_{n}(x) T_{n}(t) \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} X_{n}(x) T''_{n}(t) + c^{2} \omega^{2} X_{n}(x) T_{n}(t) \qquad \text{(as $X'' = - \omega^{2} X$)} \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} [T''_{n}(t) + c^{2} \omega^{2} T_{n}(t)]X_{n}(x) \\
&= 0 \qquad \text{(from the PDE)}
\end{align}

We know that $X_{n}(x) \ne 0$, hence we must have

$$T''_{n}(t) + c^{2} \omega^{2} T_{n}(t) = 0$$

We also need to use our initial conditions. Again, as $X_{n}(x) \ne 0$

\begin{align}
v_{t}(x,0) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} X_{n}(x) T'_{n}(0) \\
&= 0 \\
\implies T'_{n}(0) &= 0 \qquad \forall n
\end{align}

Notice that this is essentially the same condition we have at $(1)$. Applying the last condition

\begin{align}
v(x,0) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} X_{n}(x) T_{n}(0) \\
&= -u_{\text{stat}}(x)
\end{align}

which is essentially what we have written at $(3)$. So, just like we did after $(3)$, we multiply both sides by $X_{m}(x)$ and integrate over the domain, which gives

\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} T_{n}(0) \int_{0}^{L} X_{n}(x) X_{m}(x) dx &= -\int_{0}^{L} X_{m}(x) u_{\text{stat}}(x) dx
\end{align}

and using the result at $(4)$, we get that

$$T_{n}(0) = - \frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L} X_{n}(x) u_{\text{stat}}(x) dx$$

which is the other condition.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful. I didn't quite understand why you multiplied $\cos \left( \frac{(2m+1)\pi x}{2L} \right)$ on both sides, but when I was at the same place in the process, I decided to use the formula for fourier coefficients and see if that worked, so $A_n = \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L [f(x)cos(\omega_n x)]dx$, where in this case $f(x)=-u_{stat} (x)$. And the solution was (if anyone is wondering): $A_n = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{2K}{c^2 L \omega_n^3}$, which was correct.

Comment: Given a Fourier series $$v = \sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} X_{n}(x) T_{n}(t)$$ how can we possibly isolate the coefficients and compute them explicitly? Well, if we apply our inhomogeneous condition, we get $$v|_{t=0} = \sum_{n \ge 0} A_{n} X_{n}(x) = f(x)$$ Now, to isolate the coefficients in some sense we want the $X_{n}$ to 'disappear', or to be annihilated. One way to do this is to multiply both sides of our inhomogeneous condition by our basis $X_{m}$ and integrate over the domain to use the [orthogonality relations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html).